# Where is the edge loop hotkey set in the keymap section of 2.8?

Tags: interface, shortcut

`Alt+LMB` does nothing, and I'm trying to determine if this is a bug and the nature of the issue so I can report it. In looking at the keymap settings, I can find "Edge Ring Select" twice, but not "Edge Loop" which should be `Alt+LMB`.

Can someone tell me where specifically I can find this hotkey to make sure it's present and set? (ie what is the full path to it in the Keymap tree, or what search term will show it)?

Is there a way to add it back manually?

I've tested this on the Feb and April 14th builds of 2.8 and the same issue is present. I've also reset to factory defaults.

[image]

Comment: It's fine for me in `1f1eedf8ad90` (2019-04-08). The two entries for edge ring select probably treat existing selections differently. For me the binding with shift has the *Toggle Select* parameter enabled, though I'm not exactly sure what that does.

Comment: @gandalf3 someone having a brain freeze? ;) Holding shift when selecting will add/subtract from existing selection instead of replacing it.

Comment: @sambler I know that ;) For some reason I was expecting for *Extend* and *Deselect* to be enabled in the `shift` binding, but now that I see *Toggle Select* seems to mean exactly that, it makes sense.

Comment: @gandalf3 actually some clarity of the difference between extend and toggle might be worth looking for.

Comment: @sambler From just playing around with it just now, I think it is: the default behavior is to discard any preexisting selection. *Extend* preserves the existing selection and just adds to it. *Deselect* **only** deselects. *Toggle* deselects if the clicked element was already selected, and *extends* otherwise.   The options don't really make sense to enable at the same time and seem to override eachother in some way I haven't bothered to figure out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd>-Select can be found under "Loop Select" and should exist in the default settings.

Edge loop select refers to edges that are connected end to end, while edge ring is a ring of parallel edges between two edge loops.

[image: sample edge loop and ring]

Comment: Accepting this, but also adding my own answer as I figured out why it wasn't working!

Answer (score 0):

If you're running Linux, <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd>+<kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd> is a window manager hotkey that lets you drag windows around by clicking anywhere on them. As soon as you click <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd>, the window manager blocks the left click from reaching any programs.

So Linux users will need to either disable or remap this function in the window manager, or remap it in Blender.

In 2.8 you can also, while in edit mode, go to the menu at the top of the 3D view port and choose `Select -> Select Loops -> Select Edge Loops`. This requires one edge to be selected first, and if you try to bind a new hot key from this menu, it will be the two-step version of `select edge loops`.

If you want the modifier+click functionality, you have to go to Edit -> Preferences -> Keymap and search for "Loop Select", then rebind both versions of it to another modifier key such as the Windows logo Key (which Blender calls `cmd`). The <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd>+<kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd>+<kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd> version becomes <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd>+<kbd>[image: Windows key]</kbd>+<kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd> while the <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd>+<kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd> version becomes <kbd>[image: Windows key]</kbd>+<kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd>. The two versions allow for shift to add and remove from an existing selection, although the labeling here could be much clearer.

Comment: Ahh yes, been a few years since I set that. I set the window manager to use the window (cmd) modifier key.

Answer (score 0):

In the keymap editor, search for loop select or ring select.